# how to trigger a Gutenberg image gallery lightbox

Tags: block-editor

@ our Gutenberg-produced [blog post](https://mandoemedia.com/blog/case-study-ribs-and-burgers/), there is a Gutenberg gallery at the bottom of the post.

```
<figure class="wp-block-gallery has-nested-images columns-default is-cropped">
  <figure class="wp-block-image size-large"><a href="https://mandoemedia.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/04/Mandoe-Ribs-Burgers-1.jpg"><img loading="lazy" width="1024" height="683" data-id="20575" src="https://mandoemedia.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/04/Mandoe-Ribs-Burgers-1-1024x683.jpg" alt="" class="wp-image-20575"></a></figure>
  <figure class="wp-block-image size-large"><a href="https://mandoemedia.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/04/Mandoe-Ribs-Burgers-6.jpg"><img loading="lazy" width="1024" height="683" data-id="20577" src="https://mandoemedia.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/04/Mandoe-Ribs-Burgers-6-1024x683.jpg" alt="" class="wp-image-20577"></a></figure>
  <figure class="wp-block-image size-large"><a href="https://mandoemedia.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/04/Mandoe-Ribs-Burgers-10.jpg"><img loading="lazy" width="1024" height="683" data-id="20579" src="https://mandoemedia.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/04/Mandoe-Ribs-Burgers-10-1024x683.jpg" alt="" class="wp-image-20579"></a></figure>
  <figure class="wp-block-image size-large"><a href="https://mandoemedia.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/04/Mandoe-Ribs-Burgers-11.jpg"><img loading="lazy" width="1024" height="683" data-id="20574" src="https://mandoemedia.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/04/Mandoe-Ribs-Burgers-11-1024x683.jpg" alt="" class="wp-image-20574"></a></figure>
  <figure class="wp-block-image size-large"><a href="https://mandoemedia.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/04/Mandoe-Ribs-Burgers-16.jpg"><img loading="lazy" width="1024" height="683" data-id="20578" src="https://mandoemedia.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/04/Mandoe-Ribs-Burgers-16-1024x683.jpg" alt="" class="wp-image-20578"></a></figure>
  <figure class="wp-block-image size-large"><a href="https://mandoemedia.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/04/Mandoe-Ribs-Burgers-17.jpg"><img loading="lazy" width="1024" height="683" data-id="20573" src="https://mandoemedia.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/04/Mandoe-Ribs-Burgers-17-1024x683.jpg" alt="" class="wp-image-20573"></a></figure>
  <figure class="wp-block-image size-large"><a href="https://mandoemedia.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/04/Mandoe-Ribs-Burgers-18.jpg"><img loading="lazy" width="1024" height="683" data-id="20576" src="https://mandoemedia.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/04/Mandoe-Ribs-Burgers-18-1024x683.jpg" alt="" class="wp-image-20576"></a></figure>
</figure>
```

If I were to add a button to the top of the post, how would I make that button click to trigger the gallery lightbox to open, please?

Help appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case I think it would be easiest to simply ignore any Gutenberg-specific implementation and set up the button's click event to `click()` the first linked image in the gallery listing.

The following searches the page for "gallery buttons" and the first linked image in a gallery block, then sets up the buttons to execute a `click` event on the first linked image when clicked.

```js
const initPostGalleryButtons = () => {
  const btns = document.querySelectorAll( '.fl-module-fl-post-content .gallery-btn' )
  const first_gallery_link = document.querySelector( '.fl-module-fl-post-content .wp-block-gallery .wp-block-image>a' )

  if( ! btns.length || ! first_gallery_link )
    return

  const openGallery = () => first_gallery_link.click()

  for ( const btn of btns )
    btn.addEventListener( 'click', openGallery )
}

document.addEventListener( 'DOMContentLoaded', initPostGalleryButtons )
```